# Getting SSL PROTOCOL EXCEPTION in android using sslEngine

Tags: android, ssl, sslengine

I am getting this error in android version 7 while using SSL engine after handshaking is done.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read
error: ssl=0xb823f9c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:192 0xdc77ca9f:0x00000000)
```

The SSL context I am using is TLSv1.2 I know it is hard to answer without any code But I am not allowed to write the string connections, The app is connected to the server via plain Http text but because of privacy, I can not write code.

Comment: can any one tell me what to do,I really don't know